# How to save a query in Dremio?

Tags: dremio

Dremio provides a really nice GUI to download and save  data generated after your query run.

[image]

However, I want to save my query (instead of query result) in dremio so that I can anytime (in future) refer the query that I wrote. Is there a way to achieve this?

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, I thought it might be helpful to provide a solution. What you are describing can be solved with a key functionality of Dremio. Instead of going through the difficulty of searching for your old query; I would have suggested creating a VDS (Virtual Data Set) by way of the UI. After a successful run of your query you can save it
[Dremio Save Dataset Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UeLj.png) as a VDS.

After selecting the save button you will be asked where you wish to save it; you can either save it to your default directory or a named Space you have created previously [Dremio VDS Save Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp9Hl.png).

You can query against this new VDS as though it was an actual table. Any changes made to the VDS will be saved in a history - utilizing the breadcrumb trail on the right side of the UI one can navigate to prior versions.

You can now further accelerate this query through creation of a Dremio Reflection...but that goes beyond the scope of your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the left upper corner, you should look for Jobs menu:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can see jobs menu. But once this list gets huge, it become difficult to find the completed job of my interest. Is there a way to save some of the jobs separately in some folder  (or something of that kind)?

Comment: I think that you have to rely just on those filters at the top: Start time, Status, etc...

Comment: Just curious. Can we tag a query? Just a usecase, All I want is I should be able to get back to the query that I wrote months back in dremio.

Comment: Take a moment to check the documentation (https://docs.dremio.com/jobs/) and please accept theanswer unless you are going to modify your question in order to make it more complete.